# Not able to increase java heap size

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have 16GB RAM on my Linux machine and have set the maximum java heap memory to 4GB using -Xmx4096m argument. But I am getting the following error when i start my process.

> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m The specified size exceeds the
>   maximum representable size. Could not create the Java virtual machine.

It works fine when i set the value to 2048m.

Is there any other configuration parameter that i need to change to increase the heap size ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you run 64bit linux or 32bit?

Comment: what is your machine architecture ? on a 32 bit machine max heap size available is 1628MB ?

Comment: Thanks for the respones guys. I am running 64bit linux. It works fine with heap size of 2048MB.

Comment: Still you are not specified if your JVM is 32 or 64 bit. FAQ quote: "On 64-bit operating systems running the 32-bit VM, the max heap size can be higher, approaching 4G on many Solaris systems." http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit $ java -version is able to tell you which JVM you are using.

Comment: Im using 32-bit JVM. Could that be a problem. Probably that explains the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

its not only about how much RAM you have

on a 32 bit machine max heap available is 1628MB 
on a 64 bit machine max heap available is 2^64 (theoretically) but there are limitations

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using?
Take a look at the [Oracle Hotspot FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html). Look out for the following section:

> Why can't I get a larger heap with the 32-bit JVM?

If you are using a 32-bit system, lower it to 1.6G. For 64-bit systems, check the supported systems list in the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try -Xmx4066M
It's a bit less than 4G

after typing to command prompt (cmd)

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"
```

Shows me following result
in order to get from bit's to Mb you have to
divide it by 1024^2=1'048'576 bits/mb

- uintx HeapSizePerGCThread = 87241520 bit (83,1999... MiB)
- uintx InitialHeapSize = 268435456 bit (256 MiB)
- uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold  = 134217728 bit (128 MiB)
- uintx MaxHeapSize  = 4263510016 bit (4066 MiB)<4G

When I've tryed changing -Xmx4G and display this is showed me MaxHeapSize =0...

### But when i do -XmX4066M it works for me.

***My problem*** is with InitalHeapSize I've Tryed changing -Xms2G or -Xms2000M and it doesnt work for me or it refreshes every time...

After I make a new project

```
public class MaxMemory {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long totalMem = rt.totalMemory();
    long maxMem = rt.maxMemory();
    long freeMem = rt.freeMemory();
    long usedMem= totalMem-freeMem;
    double megs = 1048576.0;

    System.out.println ("Max Memory:   " + maxMem + " (" + (maxMem/megs) + " MiB)");
    System.out.println ("Total Memory: " + totalMem + " (" + (totalMem/megs) + " MiB)");
    System.out.println ("Used:  " + usedMem + " (" + (usedMem/megs) + " MiB)");
    System.out.println ("Free Memory:  " + freeMem + " (" + (freeMem/megs) + " MiB)");  

}
```

it throws me following resoult in one of my programs:

> Max Memory:   259522560 (247.5 MiB)
>
> Total Memory: 259522560 (247.5 MiB)
>
> Used:  246496784 (235.07765197753906 MiB)
>
> Free Memory:  13025776 (12.422348022460938 MiB)

and i may not increase this ***"Max Memory"*** which i think is **InitialHeapSize**

And I've tried to change it in

> Controll Panel > java control panel >  java (tab) > view (button) >
>   RuntimeParameter (block) > -Xms2000M

, of course after going out I click **apply** but Nothing happened... still run out of my memory ;'[